# How is "std::cin>>value" evaluated in a while loop?

Tags: c++, cin, operator-precedence

Currently I'm self-learning C++ Primer 5th. Here comes something I'm not sure. (I couldn't find the exact relevant question on F.A.Q).

Consider this while loop:

```
while(std::cin>>value){...}  \\value here was defined as int.
```

The text book says:

> That expression reads the next number from the standard input and stores that number in value. The input operator (§ 1.2, p. 8) returns its left operand, which in this case is std::cin. This condition, therefore, tests std::cin.When we use an istream as a condition, the effect is to test the state of the stream. If the stream is valid—that is, if the stream hasn’t encountered an error—then the test succeeds.

My question is: does `std::cin` read input into `value` first then test the validation of `std::cin`, or test `std::cin` first then decide whether to read into 'value'? I'm quite confused about when it "returns its left operand".

Comment: Knowing that `std::cin>>value` is simply `std::cin.operator>>(value)` might help y ou.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remember that your code is equivalent to:

```
while (std::cin.operator>>(value)) { }
```

Or:

```
while (1) {
    std::cin >> value ;
    if (!std::cin) break ;
}
```

The "code" always tries to read from `std::cin` into `value` before testing `std::cin`.

Let's look at the quote:

> [...] The input operator (§ 1.2, p. 8) returns its left operand, which in this case is std::cin. [...]

This only means that `std::cin.operator>>(value)` return `std::cin`.

> This condition, therefore, tests std::cin. When we use an istream as a condition, the effect is to test the state of the stream. If the stream is valid—that is, if the stream hasn’t encountered an error—then the test succeeds.

What the text book says is that after trying to read an integer from `std::cin` to `value`, the `>>` operator returns `std::cin`. If `std::cin` is in a good state after reading `value`, then the test passes, otherwize it fails.

---

Some extra details:

When you do `std::cin >> value`, you basically call `istream::operator>>(int&)`, and *yes* there is a test *inside* that method: If the test passes, then the internal state of `std::cin` is set to [`ios_base::goodbit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/ios_base::goodbit), if it fails, internal state is set to on of the error flag ([`eofbit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/ios_base::eofbit), [`failbit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/ios_base::failbit) or [`badbit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/ios_base::badbit)).

Depending on the [`exception mask`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/) for `std::cin`, if the internal test fails, an exception [may be thrown](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/#exceptions).

From your quote:

> When we use an istream as a condition, the effect is to test the state of the stream.

This basically mean that:

```
if (std::cin) { }
```

Is [equivalent](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/) to:

```
if (!std::cin.fail()) { }
```

And `std::cin.fail()` check for `failbit` or `badbit`. This means that `while (std::cin >> value) { }` does not test the `eofbit` flag and will only fail when the input cannot be converted to an integer value.

Comment: Thank you so much!!T.T your second example did save my life, Now everything clear for me.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts T.T.

Answer (score 4):

> does std::cin read input into value first then test the validation of
>   std::cin, or test std::cin first then decide whether to read into
>   'value'

`cin` first tries to read an `int` from the standard input, if `cin` is in a good state: if it fails to, it will set the stream to a bad state; regardless of the operation done, it will return the stream itself (i.e. the "left operand" -- `cin`), that will allow you to check for success or failure.

If you wanted to explicitly test the validity of the stream first and only then try to read the value, you would have:

```
while (cin && cin >> value)
```

but it's pretty redundant, since, as I've told you, `cin` will not even try to read `value` if it's already in a bad state.

Comment: Just realized how concise your words is..I'm jotting down your explanation now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There are two tests.

The first test is the condition of the while statement

```
while(std::cin>>value){...}
```

This condition tests the result of calling operator function `operator >>`

The second test is a condition within the operator. If the state of the stream `std::cin` is good then the function tries to read an integer from the string. Otherwise it returns `std::cin` with the current erroneous state of `std::cin`.

In the while condition there is an expression

```
std::cin>>value
```

This expression must be evaluated. So this condition tests the result of the call of `operator >>` .

The result of the operator is the stream `std::cin` But it can be contextually converted to a bool value due to operator

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

which returns the state of the stream

```
!fail().
```

Comment: Your answer is not wrong but (IMO) a bit misleading because your "second condition" will actually be done before the "first test".

Comment: @Hoit Yeah I was struggle with the 2 given answers just now,, Thanks for pointing out this!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you wouldn't have any confusion with a simple function call:

```
SomeReturnType some_function(int&);
while (some_function(value)) { ... }
```

The above code will repeatedly call `some_function` until the return value from the function call, interpreted as a boolean, is `false`. The function is called for each step in the loop. Whether the function changes the value of `value` is up to the function. It certainly can do so, and presumably will do so (but that's an issue for the designer of the function).

The loop `while (std::cin>>value) {...}` is completely equivalent to `while (std::cin.operator>>(value)) {...}`. This is just a function call to the member function `std::stream::operator>>(int&)`.

Comment: Yeah I got it, that's why need read into value first! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume your "value" is for example an int

- The stream tries to read input until the next whitespace.
- if eof is found ... -> then the state will be set to "eof", >> will return the stream and the boolean evaluation of the stream will return false
- if an error (I/O for example) happens during the reading process, the state will be set to "bad", >> will return the stream and the boolean evaluation of the stream will return false
- if whitespace has been found, then a conversion from the read characters to int (the above assumption) will be attempted. If it fails (because the read input is for example: "xx" and not a number) the state of the stream will be set to "fail". >> will return the stream and the boolean evaluation of the stream will return false
- if we are so far down the chain, eof was not found, no IO error (or other) happened, and the characters -> int conversion was successful. >> will return the stream and the boolean evaluation of the stream will return true.

  And your "value" will contain the appropriate value

Comment: Actually, when just `std::ios_base::eofbit` is set, the stream won't convert to `false`! The stream only converts to `false` when `std::ios_base::failbit` or `std::ios_base::badbit` are set. `std::ios_base::eofbit` is set, e.g., when reading the last line of a file which isn't terminated with a newline. The line can happily be read and processed. Only when an input operation fails, e.g., when an attempt is made to read something when `std::ios_state::eofbit` is set, the stream is set into a mode where it returns `false`, normally by having `std::ios_base::failbit` set.

Answer (score 0):

The operator first reads the value and then returns a reference to the object.  The `while` statement first calls that operator and second tests the returned value.