# Why does while(file >> a) work?

Tags: c++, file, while-loop

I have to read from a file where are only few numbers. Read it, sum them up and that's it. (Learning C++). If I was using fstream::eof() function it read the last number twice, so I did it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    fstream file;
    int a = 0, sum = 0;

    file.open("nums.txt",fstream::in);

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "Unable to open file!\n" << endl;
    }

    while (file >> a) {
        cout << a << endl;
        sum += a;
    }

    cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;

    file.close();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Now it doesn't read last number twice, but I don't understand what is happening in while() brackets, I thought if I read 0 it would stop, but it reads it as well. Is file >> a actually returning something like "managed to read" = 1 and "fail" = 0  ??

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is "std::cin>>value" evaluated in a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395801/how-is-stdcinvalue-evaluated-in-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 7):

> Is file >> a actually returning something

Yes. It returns a reference to `file` itself. And `std::fstream` is contextually convertible to `bool` via its [`operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

It essentially returns the logical inverse of the streams `fail()` member.

Answer (score 3):

The `>>` operator, when applied to a stream, returns that same stream. This is why you can write stuff like `file >> a >> b`. It also happens that the stream has an `operator bool()` that is equivalent to `!fail()`. Thus, once the stream has reached eof, the `operator bool()` will return `false`, and since `>>` returns the stream, `while (file >> a)` will loop until the stream hits eof (or has an error).