# How to read unknown number of inputs?

Tags: c++, algorithm, while-loop, c++14, user-input

I am learning C++ using the book C++ Primer.

In *Section 1.4.3*, the following example code about reading the unknown number of inputs is given.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  int sum = 0, value = 0;
  // read until end-of-file, calculating a running total of all values read
  while (std::cin >> value)
  sum += value; // equivalent to sum = sum + value
  std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

According to the book, if we give an input of `3 4 5 6`, the output will be `Sum is: 18`

But when I try this on my computer(*Windows 10 with MinGW*), The code does not end. It just keeps on asking for input even if I enter a newline. It works only when I enter a non-int input like `f`.

---

**Is this expected? If yes, is there any code that stops after inputting a newline?**

I am quite new to c++ and I have already learned python, so getting stuck so early on is quite frustrating.

---

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Under Linux you would use the EOF character <Ctrl-D>

Comment: If you want to explicitly read a **line**, you should try [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Either read an entire line (via `std::getline()`) or use program arguments

Comment: Is my question wrong, if not why did I get a down vote ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to terminate your input by an End-Of-File-character (i.e. <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> on Mac/Unix), not just by an End-Of-Line (i.e. <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

A simple <kbd>Enter</kbd> is interpreted as white space, which will be simply ignored by `operator>>` when reading into an integral data type.

<kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> / End-Of-File, in contrast, makes any `operator>>` fail with an error.

See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16136924/2630032).

Note: Entering `f` will also terminate your loop, since `f` is not considered a valid integral number; Hence, `std::cin >> value` with `value` being of type `int` and an input like `f` will fail as well. To be more accurate: `operator>>` actually returns a reference to the input stream, but if reading in a value fails, `failbit` is set on the stream, and then interpreting the stream object in a boolean expression (implicitly calling `basic_istream::operator bool()`) returns `false`; So maybe the author of the book did not want to explain these details at the respective section in the book :-)

Comment: So Shouldn't this be written in the book

Comment: If the section is about explaining `operator >>` and its behaviour, then it should be explained, I suppose. If the example is about demonstrating something else, well...

Comment: One last thing, is it possible to write a code which stops after a white space

Comment: Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 4):

> Is this expected?

Yes, as `operator>>` ignores leading whitespace by default, which includes line breaks.

> If yes, is there any code that stops after inputting a newline?

Use `std::cin.getline()` or `std::getline()` instead of `operator>>`.  You can then use `operator>>` with a `std::istringstream` to parse values from each line, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    int sum, value;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a set of numbers, or a blank line to exit: ";
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, line) || line.empty())
            break;

        // read until end-of-line, calculating a running total of all values read
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        sum = 0;
        while (iss >> value)
            sum += value; // equivalent to sum = sum + value

        std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/Ao67ZI)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this expected?

**Yes**, Thats what  `while (std::cin >> value)` does. See this answer for more explanations: [How is "std::cin>>value" evaluated in a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395801/how-is-stdcinvalue-evaluated-in-a-while-loop)

> is there any code that stops after inputting a newline?

**No**, as `>>` simply ignore a white space(also @StephanLechner mentioned it)

What you can do instead is:

1. Just give a condition; if it satisfies just `break` the loop. you
   can also provide a console out to make it more understandable to the
   user. For example:

   ```
   std::cout << "Enter value to sum or press -1 to exit" << std::endl;

   while (std::cin >> value && value != -1) // if value == -1, loop stops.
   {
       sum += value;
   }
   ```
2. You can simply terminate by the end of character:

   - <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> on Windows
   - <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> on Mac/Unix

Comment: Will this loop break only if input is -1

Comment: no, You can also chose the other options here, using the end of file chars, which Stephan Lechner mentioned.

Comment: THank you very much