# what should i do to stop while(cin>>word) from taking input

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am trying to take user input (strings) and store them in a vector . but this ***`while cin` doesn't stop taking user input***. I know there is a `getline()` function etc. also but why does while getline or while cin dont stop taking user input? any solution?

```
string word;
   vector <string> text;

   while (cin >> word) {
      text.push_back(word);
   }
```

Comment: When do you want it to stop? See dupe: [What's the difference between while(cin) and while(cin >> num)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483126/whats-the-difference-between-whilecin-and-whilecin-num). Here is another: [How is "std::cin>>value" evaluated in a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395801/how-is-stdcinvalue-evaluated-in-a-while-loop)

Comment: when i hit the enter?

Comment: You loop will read until there's either an error, or there an end-of-file condition.

Comment: If you want to read a line, use `std::getline`. If you then want to split the line into "words", then put the line into an `std::istringstream` and use your loop to get the words from that stream instead.

Comment: got my answer. ctrl+Z can solve the problem.

Comment: Note that `Ctrl-Z` set the `eofbit` flag. This means you can't read more input until you clear that flag.